# JavaScript Dynamic Adding of elements

Tags: javascript

Please look at the following code

---

```
mydiv1.innerHTML=mydiv1.innerHTML + '<label>*Functional Area:<span class="small">Enter Company Name</span></label><input type="text" name="FunctionalArea_"'+counter1+' id="company" /><label class="spacing">*Experience:<span class="small">Number of years</span></label><select name="Exp_In_FA_"'+ counter1 +' id="experience"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>morethan 5</option</select><input type="button" value="Add" id="bt1" onclick="generate()" style="font-size:8pt;height:25px;width:55px"/>'
```

Now the above javascript code is called properly and new elements get embedded at the desired location. But the problem is that when these values are passed to servlet, i am unable to retrieve Exp_In_FA_0 by using request.getParameter("Exp_In_FA_0"). It simply returns NULL. Please correct me where i am doing wrong?
Sorry that i am unable to post the code in multiple lines. The code tag takes everything in single line only

Comment: What servlet and what request? Please provide more context. Also you could split up the code block manually, you'd just have to indent every line

Comment: `name="FunctionalArea_"'+counter1+'` should be `name="FunctionalArea_'+counter1+'"`

Comment: all these controls exist in some <form/> or not ??

Comment: @Furqan: They exist in the same form

Comment: @ oracle certified professional: Could u please post the entire line..I am confused where to change waht?

Comment: @nikil `<input type="text" name="FunctionalArea_"'+counter1+' id="company" />` should be `<input type="text" name="FunctionalArea_'+counter1+'" id="company" />`. I'm not saying that this is the answer to your whole question, though

Comment: @Pekka: The code is actually one full line. It is not correct to split one line.

Comment: @nikhil you could split it at the `+`s without breaking it

Comment: @oracle: Could u please tell what is the difference between both?

Comment: @oracle: Thanks. It worked out. But what is the difference?

Comment: @nikhil the second double quote of the `name` attribute on the first snippet `<input type="text" name="FunctionalArea_"'+counter1+' id="company" />` is after the underscore of `FunctionalArea_` but before the single quote of `'+counter1+'`. It should come after the second single quote of `'+counter1+'` thus: `name="FunctionalArea_'+counter1+'"`. Otherwise, say `counter1` is `1`, it will evaluate to `name="FunctionalArea_"1` and not `name="FunctionalArea_1"`, which I assume you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or similar tools) to see the actual genearted code (using the "Inspect Element") feature.

You might want to confirm the `name`, the `form` in which the element is added etc.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] new elements get embedded at the
>   desired location.

Check whether the name attribute of the new element laso OK in the resulting HTML document. You can do this in Firefox with selecting your input box and the surrounding HTML and from the context menu choosing "Yiew source of selection". - Or you can use Google Chrome's "Inspect" feature to watch the element.

Comment: View selection source might not work correctly if the elements are dynamically geneated via Javascript.

Comment: @Nivas Thnaks. Added Chrome option too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read here
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=innerhtml+form+not+passed

and

http://domscripting.com/blog/display/99

> First of all, use the DOM to create a
>   block level element—such as a
>   div—using createElement. Then update
>   the innerHTML property of this
>   newly-created element. Finally, insert
>   the updated element into the document
>   using a DOM method like appendChild or
>   insertBefore:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.appendChild(newdiv);
```